# $L^p$ regularity for wave equations with coercive boundary conditions

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Suppose we have the wave type equation 
$$\partial^2_tu - L u = 0$$ on a compact manifold with boundary, where  $L$ is a second order strongly elliptic operator with coercive boundary conditions (not necessarily Dirichlet or Neumann) making it self-adjoint. I wanted some references for $L^p$ regularity results for such equations, if such results exist at all. I don't think the standard Calderon-Zygmund theory or the standard pseudodifferential approach hold because of the boundary conditions. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't see how you could expect *elliptic* regularity for a *hyperbolic* equation..

Comment: @Kofi Oops, my bad! Corrected.

Comment: Can you specify your boundary condition, and your assumptions on the initial data?